# Does not affect the transition in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

With js I change the texts by using innerHTML but even if I have the transition set, when I change the text I don't see that it does not pay attention to it, so it changes suddenly.

```js
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("slider-text-1").innerHTML = "Hello World";
  document.getElementById("slider-text-2").innerHTML = "descripcioon de prueba";
});
```

```css
#slider-text-1,
#slider-text-2 {
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-slider">
  <h1 id="slider-text-1">Diseño de páginas web</h1>
  <p id="slider-text-2">Contrata tu web en el presente y mejora el futuro de tu empresa.</p>
  <div class="botones">
    <i id="btn1" class="fas fa-circle"></i>
    <i id="btn2" class="fas fa-circle"></i>
    <i id="btn3" class="fas fa-circle"></i>
    <i id="btn4" class="fas fa-circle"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Changing the text does not alter any CSS property so no transition will occur.

Comment: `transition` only applies to CSS properties and not content.

Comment: Also, you should not use `.innerHTML` when you are not including any HTML in the string. Use `.textContent` instead.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: And is there a simple way to add any effect whatsoever to change the text by setContent in the js ?

Comment: @Rodrypaladin Quick but ugly: use `element.style.maxHeight = element.offsetHeight()` at beginning of function, update content, `element.style.maxHeight = 10000` or an obscene number

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that transition property only applies to modification in other CSS properties (for example the width or height of an element).

What you need to do is apply a class that contains a CSS animation in the moment of content change, so what you can do is:

```js
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("slider-text-1").innerText = "Hello World";
    document.getElementById("slider-text-2").innerText =
      "descripcioon de prueba";

    document.getElementById("slider-text-1").classList.add("fade-in");
    document.getElementById("slider-text-2").classList.add("fade-in");

    setTimeout(function () {
      document.getElementById("slider-text-1").classList.remove("fade-in");
      document.getElementById("slider-text-2").classList.remove("fade-in");
    }, 1000);
  });
```

```css
    .fade-in {
      -webkit-animation: fade-in 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1) both;
      animation: fade-in 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1) both;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
    @keyframes fade-in {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="info-slider">
      <h1 id="slider-text-1">Diseño de páginas web</h1>
      <p id="slider-text-2">
        Contrata tu web en el presente y mejora el futuro de tu empresa.
      </p>
      <div class="botones">
        <button id="btn1" class="fas fa-circle"></button>
        <button id="btn2" class="fas fa-circle"></button>
        <button id="btn3" class="fas fa-circle"></button>
        <button id="btn4" class="fas fa-circle"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

(I change your `i` tags to buttons for commodity, you can revert it)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, changing the text inside an element is not the same thing as changing a CSS property, which is what CSS Transitions use.

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions):

> CSS transitions provide a way to control animation speed when changing
> CSS properties.

What you can do is, in addition to changing the text, change a CSS property to trigger a transition. In this case, I've worked with `opacity` to create a fade out/in effect. A timer (`setTimeout()`) is needed to put a delay between the out/in.

```js
const slider1 = document.getElementById("slider-text-1");
const slider2 = document.getElementById("slider-text-2");

document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Apply the class that will hide the elements and trigger the transition
  slider1.classList.add("hidden");
  slider2.classList.add("hidden");
  
  // Have to wait a little bit before bringing the elements back into view
  // otherwise it happens so fast you won't see any effect. Here, we are
  // waiting 2 seconds to run the callback function:
  setTimeout(function(){
    // Change the text first
    slider1.textContent = "Hello World";
    slider2.textContent = "descripcioon de prueba";
    
    // Remove the class that hides the elements, which will put their
    // opacity back to it's original value.
    slider1.classList.remove("hidden");
    slider2.classList.remove("hidden"); 
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
#slider-text-1, #slider-text-2 {
  /* Any property you want to transition must have a defined
     starting value so that the system knows where to begin the
     transition at. */
  opacity:1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

/* This class is added when the button is clicked, which will
   trigger the transition. */
#slider-text-1.hidden, #slider-text-2.hidden  { opacity: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="info-slider">
  <h1 id="slider-text-1">Diseño de páginas web</h1>
  <p id="slider-text-2">Contrata tu web en el presente y mejora el futuro de tu empresa.</p>
  <div class="botones">
    <i id="btn1" class="fas fa-circle">x</i>
    <i id="btn2" class="fas fa-circle">x</i>
    <i id="btn3" class="fas fa-circle">x</i>
    <i id="btn4" class="fas fa-circle">x</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify what property you want the text to transition when you change the text. And change it by adding or deleting a class.
transition does not apply by itself, and change another property of that object using another class to apply the transition. Below is a ready-made animation for your question.

```js
var counter = 0;
var timer;
function changeText(button) {
  if (counter == 0) {
    document.getElementById("slider-text-1").classList.add('elem-reverse-right-animate');
    document.getElementById("slider-text-2").classList.add('elem-reverse-right-animate');
    document.getElementById("slider-text-1").classList.remove('elem-right-animate');
    document.getElementById("slider-text-2").classList.remove('elem-right-animate');

    timer = setTimeout(changeText, 1000);
    counter = 1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("slider-text-1").classList.remove('elem-reverse-right-animate');
    document.getElementById("slider-text-2").classList.remove('elem-reverse-right-animate');
    document.getElementById("slider-text-1").innerHTML = "Hello World";
    document.getElementById("slider-text-2").innerHTML = "descripcioon de prueba";
    document.getElementById("slider-text-1").classList.add('elem-right-animate');
    document.getElementById("slider-text-2").classList.add('elem-right-animate');
    clearTimeout(timer);
    counter = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
#slider-text-1,
#slider-text-2 {
  transition: all 2s;
}

.elem-right-animate {
  animation: right-animate 2s ease forwards;
}

.elem-reverse-right-animate {
  animation: reverse-right-animate 2s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes right-animate {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes reverse-right-animate {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="info-slider">
  <h1 id="slider-text-1">Diseño de páginas web</h1>
  <p id="slider-text-2">Contrata tu web en el presente y mejora el futuro de tu empresa.</p>
  <div class="botones">
    <i id="btn1" class="fas fa-circle"></i>
    <i id="btn2" class="fas fa-circle"></i>
    <i id="btn3" class="fas fa-circle"></i>
    <i id="btn4" class="fas fa-circle"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="btn1" onclick="changeText()">change Text</button>
```